# How to convert Azure pfx key to pkcs#1

Tags: openssl, pkcs#1

The company I work for has it's certificates in Azure. So when you download them they are in pfx format. I get that they are a bundle and that you can use openssl to extract different version keys. The product tableau requires the certificate as a crt file and key. I have successfully extracted that using Openssl. However it also requires the certificate as a pkcs#1 file and key. I can find lots of articles and commands for converting pkcs#8 to pkcs#1 such as https://gist.github.com/gtaban/410db2351e52ae36a2a636f3cc6f86ac but not for converting pfx to pkcs#1. I can imagine it is a two-stage process so I have been looking for pfx to pkcs#8 but haven't had any luck there either. Can anyone help with how to convert pfx to pkcs#1.
Thanks!

Comment: To be clear, pkcs1 format is sometimes used for an RSA _private_ key especially in things using or designed to work with OpenSSL; converting key in pfx (aka pkcs12) to this format is indeed two stages with openssl: `openssl pkcs12 -in pfx -nocerts -nodes | openssl {rsa|pkey} -traditional [-$cipher]` (the output is encrypted if you specify a cipher to use, and not encrypted otherwise). If using OpenSSL 3.0.x up and the pfx uses older encryption (in particular RC2-40 was common until recently and is still found) add `-legacy` to the lefthand part of the pipeline ...

Comment: ... pkcs1 format is almost never used for a bare public key, and _cannot_ be used for a certificate which you say you want, so that part is not affected. And this is not programming or development.

Comment: PS: the page you link is partly out of date and is flat wrong about EC: there is no PKCS1 format for EC, and the 'traditional' format output by that command is **SEC1** (rfc5915) not PKCS1 (rfc8017 et pred). I would not follow advice from people who don't know the subject they are talking/writing about.

Comment: Thanks heaps @Dave for such a quick response! When I run the command like this: openssl pkcs12 -in azurecertificate.pfx -nocerts -nodes | openssl {rsa|pkey} -traditional   it fails with this: 'pkey}' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: Also, Tableau requires the certificate and key. I ran this command to get a certificate (.cer) out of the pfx file: openssl pkcs12 -in pfxfilename.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out certificate.crt  Are you suggesting you can use that extracted certificate with the pkcs1 key your command will produce?

Comment: (1) That syntax is not to be written literallly but rather is an abbreviation for two options: you can use either `... | openssl rsa -traditional [-$cipher]` OR `... | openssl pkey -traditional [-$cipher]` -- where in either case '...' is called ellipsis and means basically 'substitute the same thing as before'. And to be clear `[-$cipher]` also is not written literally but means you can either omit or include an argument of the form `-something` where `something` is replaced by the name of a suitable cipher, typically `des3-cbc` or `aes-128-cbc` or `aes-192-cbc` or `aes-256-cbc`.

Comment: (2) The key from `pkcs12 -nocerts` (converted as necessary) should certainly match the cert from `pkcs12 -nokeys -clcerts`; whether these alone can be used without any chain cert(s) varies depending on what you want to use them for. For example an SSL/TLS server used with older clients always needed the chain certs except for a selfsigned cert and with modern clients _sometimes_ does depending on the client(s) and the the CA(s) issuing the certs; an email signer might not, and an OCSP responder or TSA never does.

Comment: Thanks heaps Dave! openssl pkcs12 -in azurecertificate.pfx -nocerts -nodes | openssl rsa -traditional and that wrote a key that appears to be in the pkcs#1 format because it has "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" as the header. Can I just copy that to notepad and save it as a .key file? Or do I have to do something more for it to be pkcs#1 file in the .key file format that Tableau requires?

Comment: (1) you can redirect the output of any program including openssl to a file with `>filename` on all systems (but maybe not if you use PowerShell on Windows?). Assuming notepad means Windows, you _can_ use that instead _IF_ you write the file as 'ANSI' or (Win10 up only) 'UTF-8 [no BOM]'; if you use either of the UTF-16 encodings (called Unicode below Win10) or the UTF-8 with BOM encoding (the only one below Win10) the result is a file that _visually appears_ to be PEM but in fact is not, and will not work in many programs, though I don't know Tableau for sure (see next)

Comment: (2) yes "BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY" is PKCS1, and is PEM given you avoid the notepad issue above. I don't know (anything) about Tableau, but if it wants PKCS1 PEM and this is PKCS1 PEM then this is what it wants.

Comment: That perfectly answers my question @dave_thompson_085 ! I believe you have to click "Answer my question" for me to mark it as an answer though? I think your good answers might be all comments? At least that is what this page says? I really appreciate your help and would like you to be recognised for having the answer to my question. it was really helpful! https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387126/green-tick-missing-next-to-answer

Comment: Yes, these are comments. Stackoverflow questions -- and thus answers -- are supposed to be about problems in programming or development, which this is not, and I try not to violate policy even if you or others do. Actually this doesn't really belong even in comments, which are supposed to be for clarifying or improving the Q (or A), but I consider that a lesser offense since any user can request comments be deleted, while deleting a Q or A (IIRC especially an accepted A) is harder.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I am grateful to you and Stackoverflow for your help. I am also really sorry I violated policy and got it all wrong.